# Update Table with rows from a different Table using Loop in OracleDB

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am new to OracleDB and hoping to help me out. I have two tables, shown on the Image below. I want to insert any number of rows from Table2 to Table1 using a loop (maybe in procedure). This can happen by iterating through IDs from the Table2 and inserting the chosen from me into New Updated Table1 
Image:
[image]

The second table must remain the same and I must be able to do this with every rows from Table2 that suite my needs. I wrote a pseudo code, but I am not sure how to implement it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which rows are *certain rows*? Why are they Don, Harley and Jack and not (for example) Luther, Harley and Christian?

Comment: Why 5, 6 and 7 for the new ids?

Comment: Why `Luther` is not copied from table2 to table1, while other records where copied ?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, I must be able to do this with any rows I want. This is just an example. I will update my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *original* `table1`:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

        ID NAME            PHONE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Bob            123456
         2 Jake           654975
         3 Dillan         252487
```

If you want to "copy" any rows you want, then a simple option is a pure SQL `INSERT` statement, e.g.

```
SQL> insert into table1 (id, name, phone)
  2    select id, name, phone
  3    from table2
  4    where id = &par_id;
Enter value for par_id: 4

1 row created.
```

(`&par_id` is a SQL*Plus substitution variable)

Or, you could specify a few of them as `IN` list, e.g.

```
SQL> insert into table1 (id, name, phone)
  2    select id, name, phone
  3    from table2
  4    where id in (5, 6);

2 rows created.
```

The result is then

```
SQL> select * from table1 order by id;

        ID NAME            PHONE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Bob            123456
         2 Jake           654975
         3 Dillan         252487
         4 Harley         265687
         5 Jack           244587
         6 Luther         259876

6 rows selected.
```

Or, you could write a procedure to do that (in a loop? Why not, if it does the job), but I presume that the final choice depends on what exactly you want to do. Currently, I don't see a need for PL/SQL.

Comment: thanks a lot, yes I don't need to use procedure or loop, but I wanted to be able to use this everytime I want to insert rows in Table1, based on Table2. I will try to work this out by myself. Thanks a lot again for your help!